# appending to a data frame row by row character formatting issue

Tags: r, append, dataframe, rows

I am trying to build a dataframe from the output of a mapply.

Here is one example of my output.

```
> out[1:9,1]
$statistic
X-squared 
 1311.404 

$parameter
df 
 1 

$p.value
[1] 1.879366e-287

$estimate
     prop 1      prop 2 
0.001680737 0.009517644 

$null.value
NULL

$conf.int
[1] -1.000000000 -0.007153045
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

$alternative
[1] "less"

$method
[1] "2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction"

$data.name
[1] "members out of enrolled"
```

I want to put these values into a dataframe. I have 1684 rows in this matrix. I want a dataframe with 1684 rows.

I also have codes from outside of this data that I want to incorporate into the dataframe. These are strings from fwa$proc.

```
> out[,1]$p.value
[1] 1.879366e-287
> out[,1]$estimate[[1]]
[1] 0.001680737
> out[,1]$estimate[[2]]
[1] 0.009517644
> as.character(fwa$proc[1])
[1] "10022"
```

I have looked here for support for doing this. I am creating a dataframe first and then attempting to fill my dataframe from another dataframe row by row as such...

```
n<-1684

  new.df <- data.frame(cpt=character(n), FFS_prop=numeric(n), PHN_prop=numeric(n)
                 , differnce=numeric(n), results=character(n), Null_HO = character(n), Alt_HA=character(n), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here is the head.

```
> head(new.df)
  cpt FFS_prop PHN_prop differnce results Null_HO Alt_HA
1            0        0         0                       
2            0        0         0                       
3            0        0         0                       
4            0        0         0                       
5            0        0         0                       
6            0        0         0
```

Now to fill data row by row...

```
for (i in 1:n) new.df[i, ] <- data.frame(cpt = toString(fwa$proc[i])
       ,FFS_prop=round(out[,i]$estimate[[1]],5)
       ,PHN_prop=round(out[,i]$estimate[[2]],5)
       ,differnce=round(out[,i]$estimate[[1]]-out[,i]$estimate[[2]],5)
       ,results=if(out[,i]$p.value <.05) {"Reject NUll"} else {"Fail to Reject Null"}
       ,Null_HO = toString('FFS = pHN')
       ,Alt_HA = toString('FFS < PHN')
       )
```

Here is the head after the code runs.

```
> head(new.df)
  cpt FFS_prop PHN_prop differnce results Null_HO Alt_HA
1   1  0.00168  0.00952  -0.00784       1       1      1
2   1  0.00033  0.00142  -0.00109       1       1      1
3   1  0.00239  0.01461  -0.01222       1       1      1
4   1  0.00135  0.00919  -0.00783       1       1      1
5   1  0.00008  0.00180  -0.00172       1       1      1
6   1  0.00036  0.00177  -0.00141       1       1      1
```

Please friends, why don't my strings make it into the data dataframe?

I have tried to put as.character() around them, toString() around them all for naught.

Wiser ones please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried one thing and it worked. I added this piece of code  to the top of my script options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE). Even though I have that in the creation of the new.df I think because I didn't have it in the data.frame that created each row that it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` of you can also set `stringsAsFactors=F` in the data.frame in you loop. The problem is that because you are building a new data.frame in each loop, it doesn't know about the rules you've set on the data.frame that it's going to added to later. So at the time of creation, it converts it's values to a factor which is stored as a unique integer for each observed character string. Since you are only adding one value, each factor has one level so they each coded as the integer 1.

Then when you go to do the assignment to the master data.frame, that integer 1 is converted to a character "1". So the `str(new.df)` should show that your character columns are still characters, they just happen to contain the character "1" for each row.

Building `data.frames` row-by-row is always a messy process that should be avoided if at all possible. It's better to try to build data data column wise and then build your data.frame at the end. You said that `out` was the result of using `mapply` on a `prop.test` so i've created a sample

```
out<-mapply(prop.test, replicate(10, rbinom(1, size = 100, prob = .5)), 100)
```

That gives something that matches your `out` with only 10 columns I believe. But then you can extract all the p-values with

```
apply(out, 2, '[[', "p.value")
```

and all of your FSS values with

```
apply(out, 2, function(x) x$estimate[[1]])
```

so your data.frame construction would look more like

```
new.df<- data.frame(cpt = fwa$proc
    ,FFS_prop=apply(out, 2, function(x) x$estimate[[1]])
    ,PHN_prop=apply(out, 2, function(x) x$estimate[[2]])
    ,pval = apply(out, 2, '[[', "p.value")
    ,Null_HO = 'FFS = pHN'
    ,Alt_HA = 'FFS < PHN'
    ,stringsAsFactors=F
)
new.df <- transform(new.df, 
    differnce=FFS_prop-PHN_prop,
    ,results=ifelse(pval<.05, "Reject NUll", "Fail to Reject Null")
)
```

Comment: `out` is a matrix with `dim(out) == 9 1684`. Out is the output from `prop.test()` run 1684 times with `mapply()`, once for each procedure I had.

So, you are saying I should rather build each vector from the matrix first then slap the vectors together into a dataframe. Got it!!

Comment: @JenniferHayden For example, you can get all the p-values in one go with `apply(out, 2, '[[', "p.value")` and all the FSS values with `apply(out, 2, function(x) x$estimate[[1]])`. No need to loop over `i`.

Comment: @JenniferHayden I've updated my answer with a more complete example.

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks. I have never used apply in that way but avoiding the loop is always best. Clearly I need practice using these techniques. I can't upvote your answer yet, I don't have the cred, but thanks for the help.